# C Language: Write a program that would take 30 integers and prints the largest number and the smallest number

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, if-statement, for-loop

Write a program that would take 5 integers and prints the largest number and the smallest number

i tried this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5;
    int largest;
    int smallest;

    printf ( "\nEnter five integers." );
    printf ( "\nAnd I will give you the smallest and the largest." );

        scanf( "%d%d%d%d%d",  &num1, &num2, &num3, &num4, &num5 );

            if ( num1 >= num2, num3, num4, num5 )
            {
                ( "num1 = largest" );
            }

            if ( num1 <= num2, num3, num4, num5 )
            {
                ( "num1 = smallest" );
            }

            if ( num2 >= num1, num3, num4, num5 )
            {
                ( "num2 = largest" );
            }

            if ( num2 <= num1, num3, num4, num5 )
            {
                ( "num2 = smallest" );
            }

            if ( num3 >= num1, num2, num4, num5 )
            {
                ( "num3 = largest" );
            }

            if ( num3 <= num1, num2, num4, num5 )
            {
                ( "num3 = smallest" );
            }

            if ( num4 >= num1, num2, num3, num5 )
            {
                ( "num4 = largest" );
            }

            if ( num4 <= num1, num2, num3, num5 )
            {
                ( "num4 = smallest" );
            }

            if ( num5 >= num1, num2, num3, num4 )
            {
                ( "num5 = largest" );
            }

            if ( num5 <= num1, num2, num3, num4 )
            {
                ( "num5 = smallest" );
            }

            printf ( "The largest integer is %d.", largest);
            printf ( "The smallest integer is %d.", smallest);

    return 0;
}
```

but there's somthing wrong!

please can any one help to solve this ?
and if we can do this with while loop please explaine

thanks

Comment: You want to use an array and find the min value in that array. Additionally, the conditions in your if statement make no sense.

Comment: What this syntax is supposed to achieve: `num1 >= num2, num3, num4, num5`?

Comment: @EliSadoff can we do this without array ?
and if you can please add a code so i can learn how !

Regards,

Comment: You can do it without an array, but there is no reason to. Also, the best way to learn is by coding yourself, not asking others for code.

Comment: If you want to learn, you better grab a C book and read it.

Comment: @MohamadHanif so in the end you want to have 30 separate variables with all the checks that go with them? I'm sorry but that's horrible...

Comment: @EliSadoff what the problem if i read the code then i learn ?!

Comment: @EugeneSh. I insist you should add `( "num1 = largest" );` also in your first question. :)

Comment: Because then you're not learning, you're just reading what someone else did.

Comment: @EliSadoff I highly doubt that, too. :)

Comment: here you can read what someone else did: http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-find-maximum-element-in-array

Comment: @MohamadHanif Take a look at this [link](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/). Would help you get started

Comment: @EliSadoff no i read and learn what someone else did to resolve :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh You should include "`Please`" there..

Comment: I recommend that you read [this](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems?newreg=1216e0ad88d74ebbab12ba8299cc7e3c).

Comment: @RohitMat no offense, I know you're trying to help here, but that particular link is not so helpful, IMHO, a ton of code with no description, no that's not going to help in learning.

Comment: guys i just learn the C language and im in the while loop
now
i tried to do this but there's something wrong so if you want to help you welcome if not please go away :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. like, Please, I insist, sort of? :)

Comment: @Mohamad Hanif  The title of the question and the question itself contradict each other.:) Do you indeed need to find the largest and smallest numbers among 30 entered numbers?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow 5 entered numbers sorry for that

Comment: @MohamadHanif Oh, I can provide a solution only for 30 entered numbers.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow what is your solution?
without array please :P

Comment: Hint: if your program should find the maximum/minimum amoung 30'000 number, it should only be slighly different than for 30 numbers.

Comment: @MichaelWalz But I wrote a solution for 30 entered numbers without an array. Is my solution is wrong?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow actually forget my comment, it's BS, just about to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In expressions like this

```
if ( num1 >= num2, num3, num4, num5 )
```

there is used so-called comma operator and the result of the whole expression corresponds to the value `num5 != 0`.

As you asked in fact two questions: the one is about how to write a program for this assignment

> take 30 integers and prints the largest number and the smallest number

and other one is about how to write a program for this assignment

> take 5 integers and prints the largest number and the smallest number

Then I will show a demonstrative program that performs the both assignments.:)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
{   
    const size_t N = 30;

    int value;  
    int smallest, largest;

    printf ( "\nEnter %zu integers.", N );
    printf ( "\nAnd I will give you the smallest and the largest.\n" );

    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < N && scanf( "%d", &value ) == 1 )
    {
        if ( i++ == 0 )
        {
            smallest = largest = value; 
        }
        else
        {
            if ( value < smallest )
            {
                smallest = value;
            }
            else if ( largest < value )
            {
                largest = value;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( i != 0 )
    {
        printf( "\nAmong %zu entered values "
                "the smallest is %d and the largest is %d\n",
                i, smallest, largest );
    }
}

{
    int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5;

    printf ( "\nEnter five integers." );
    printf ( "\nAnd I will give you the smallest and the largest.\n" );

    scanf( "%d%d%d%d%d",  &num1, &num2, &num3, &num4, &num5 );

    if ( !( num2 < num1 ) && !( num3 < num1 ) && !( num4 < num1 ) && !( num5 < num1 ) )
    {
        printf( "The smallest number is the first number with value %d\n", num1 );
    }
    else if ( !( num3 < num2 ) && !( num4 < num2 ) && !( num5 < num2 ) )
    {
        printf( "The smallest number is the second number with value %d\n", num2 );
    }
    else if ( !( num4 < num3 ) && !( num5 < num3 ) )
    {
        printf( "The smallest number is the third number with value %d\n", num3 );
    }
    else if ( !( num5 < num4 ) )
    {
        printf( "The smallest number is the fouth number with value %d\n", num4 );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "The smallest number is the fifth number with value %d\n", num5 );
    }

    if ( !( num1 < num2 ) && !( num1 < num3 ) && !( num1 < num4 ) && !( num1 < num5 ) )
    {
        printf( "The largest number is the first number with value %d\n", num1 );
    }
    else if ( !( num2 < num3 ) && !( num2 < num4 ) && !( num2 < num5 ) )
    {
        printf( "The largest number is the second number with value %d\n", num2 );
    }
    else if ( !( num3 < num4 ) && !( num3 < num5 ) )
    {
        printf( "The largest number is the third number with value %d\n", num3 );
    }
    else if ( !( num4 < num5 ) )
    {
        printf( "The largest number is the fouth number with value %d\n", num4 );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "The largest number is the fifth number with value %d\n", num5 );
    }
}
    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter 30 integers.
And I will give you the smallest and the largest.
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30

Among 30 entered values the smallest is 1 and the largest is 30

Enter five integers.
And I will give you the smallest and the largest.
1 2 3 4 5
The smallest number is the first number with value 1
The largest number is the fifth number with value 5
```

You can yourself correct any typo in the program that you'll find.:)

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( num1 >= num2, num3, num4, num5 )
```

Is not how you compare multiple items. It is valid C code, but the comma operator executes each piece of code, left to right and the result of the statement is the result of the last piece. So your code basically becomes:

```
if (num5)
```

Which is not what you wanted. This is the way to compare multiple items:

```
if ( num1 >= num2 && num1 >= num3 && num1 >= num4 && num1 >= num5 )
```

Also,

```
( "num4 = largest" );
```

really does nothing. I think you meant

```
largest = num4;
```

A more robust way to tackle this problem is to first, ask the user how many numbers they want to compare. This does not limit you to just 5 or 30 inputs. You can then use a `for` loop to get the inputs, comparing as you go:

```
// How many numbers the user wants to input
int numInput = 0;
printf("How many numbers to compare? ");
scanf(" %d", &numInput);

// Initialize
int largest = INT_MIN;
int smallest = INT_MAX;

int input;

// Loop 
for (int i = 0; i < numInput; i++) {
    // Get next number
    printf("Enter #: ");
    scanf(" %d", &input)) {
    // Compare
    if (input > largest) largest = input;
    if (input < smallest) smallest = input;
}
// Print results
printf("Largest: %d, smallest: %d\r\n", largest, smallest);
```

Note, needs error checking. Ex: you should check the return value from `scanf` to make sure you got a number.

Comment: And what has the OP learned from your post? How to get free coding work done - it's great to help, but please critique his/her work without just giving the solution ;)

Comment: @KevinDTimm Yes, I realized that and have gone back to address original post. Taking a while....

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample program using arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n[5], i, largest, smallest;

    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d", &n[0], &n[1], &n[2], &n[3], &n[4]);
    smallest = largest = n[0];
    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        if ( smallest > n[i])
            smallest = n[i];
        if ( largest < n[i] )
            largest = n[i];
    }
    printf("%d\t%d\n", smallest, largest);
}
```

Comment: thank you !
but i still not leanred about arrays can you do this without arrays?

Comment: @MohamadHanif This is the best way of doing this IMHO - it's really ugly to try to do it without arrays (or, even better, a linked list).

Answer (score 0):

Here it is without using arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int input, i, largest, smallest;

    scanf("%d", &input);
    smallest = largest = input;
    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &input);
            if ( smallest > input)
                    smallest = input;
            if ( largest < input )
                    largest = input;
    }
    printf("%d\t%d\n", smallest, largest);
}
```